# In RHEL 9, SSH root login is not permitted. How do I set up managed nodes with Ansible?

Tags: ssh, rhel, root, ansible

I recently passed the RHCSA exam (RHEL 9). And I have started studying for RHCE EX294 with non-Red Hat affiliated materials. All of them are based on RHEL 8.

In RHEL 8, the default sshd configurartion permits root login. So it was possible to set up an ansible user and give a sudo priviliege without touching the managed nodes at all.

But RHEL 9 does not allow root login via ssh by default. So first I have to manually login to each managed nodes as root and edit the sshd configuration file to allow root login before anything.

I wonder if there is something I don't know yet about how to set up managed nodes with Ansible?
Thank you.

Comment: How is the initial installation of the systems done? I'd expect that to enable some form of remote root access. (Does RHEL still do kickstart these days? If so, then you'd have that set up via your kickstart config)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're *installing* RHEL, then as @muru says you can configure your kickstart to apply arbitrary configuration changes to your system at install time, such as adding ssh keys and/or enabling sudo access for a particular user.

If you're booting the RHEL cloud image (e.g., the KVM guest image available [here](https://access.redhat.com/downloads/content/rhel), then you can supply configuration to [cloud-init](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/configuring_and_managing_cloud-init_for_rhel_9/index) (which can be a shell script, or a cloud-config file, etc). This works for major cloud environments (openstack/aws/google/azure/etc) as well as with virtualization tools like libvirt.